# How to merge two unsorted Arrays into another considering time complexity

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity

I have two/more arrays. I want to form a new array which is sorted from the two/more array.
I dont want to combine the arrays and later sort. I wanted to get it on the go.
Time complexity is considered.

Any programming language/algorithm is fine.

Answer (score 0):

so basically you need to find for each position in the new array the smallest remaining value.
The input are the arrays a and b with n and m elements. Find min value in both arrays. compare the two values and set the smaller one to max Value in its array to prevent that it is found again. Set the min value in c.

Pseudocode:

```
merge(a[n],b[m]){
  c[n+m];
  for (i = 0, i < n+m; i++){
    aMin = getMinValue(a);
    bMin = getMinValue(b);
    if(aMin < bMin) setMinValueToMax(a,aMin)
    else setMinValueToMax(b,bMin)
    c[i] = min(aMin,bMin)
  }
  return c;
}
```

Here n is the size of the bigger array.
GetMinValue will run in O(n), just iterate over all elements. SetMinValueToMax will run in O(n) as well if you don't save the index. The for-loop will be in O(n). The body of the for is 0(3n) (2 x getMinValue + setMinValueToMax). In big O const factors can be removed which leads to a runtime of O(n^2).